# E: Type 'See' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: command-line, software-installation, updates, sudo

I got a notification.I am unable to open software update app and I am unable to install anything in terminal.It is giving this.`E: Type 'See' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Can you post the contents of file '/etc/apt/sources.list'?

Comment: The error is telling you line 4 of your sources file contains an error.  'See' is invalid; and if you look at the file (line 4) you'll note it's something you've added to it that doesn't match the other contents of the file (unless you've mucked it all up). You need to correct the line, comment it out (by putting a '#' at the start of the line) or delete it.

Comment: when I made comment on line4 then I got error for another line .I get many error in sources.list .How can I fix it?

Comment: We can't see your file, so cannot see the errors in it and thus can't really help you beyond the generic 'fix it'. @Vinu Chadran has already suggested posting your file so we can provide direct advice, but that link provides clues on fixing it or re-creating the file if necessary  (I'd `cp` or backup your filefirst  before re-creating it in case you decide you want to work on it later,  or need something from it).  *We don't even know your release of Ubuntu*

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is did you uncomment some comment lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

If it happened all of a sudden and not from install time, then I reckon something or someone had tampered with `sources.list` ...

FYI, comment lines are those starting with a `#` (comment sign) and under no circumstances should you remove a `#` as it promotes a syntactically nonsense text to be read by apt.

All valid lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` must start with `deb` or `deb-src`. The rest should be comments starting with a `#` sign.

From your error message I made a conclusion that you have tampered with comments in the following line of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
```

Head of the file should look like this (provided that you are using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver release:

```
#
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

Here is working complete `/etc/apt/sources.list` for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zFMRBb7CDT/

(You may need to replace `http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com` with another Ubuntu repository, based on your country and server preference.)